# Docker swarm make sure that one replica always access the same replica of other service

Tags: docker, load-balancing, docker-swarm

Hey at first I'm not sure if this is possible at all. I have two different services in my docker swarm. Each service is replicated n times. Service A accesses service B via dns. Below you see a simplified version of my docker compose file:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  A:
    image: <dockerimage_A>
    deploy:
      replicas: 5
  B:
    image: <dockerimage_B>
    deploy:
      replicas: 5
```

The replicas of service A accessing the replicas of service B via the DNS entry from docker ingress and send tasks to B. The runtime of the task of B variates and is blocking. Also the connection from A to B is blocking. Due to the round robin load balancing it could be the case that if one Replica combination of A and B is fast the fast A connects to another B is still blocked and the other B hasn't anything to do.

To solve this is would be ideal if one replica of A is always routed to the same replica of B. Is there a possibility to change the load balancing in that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it on my own with the following hacky solution by setting the host name for each replica individually by using the slot id.

```
 services:
  A:
    hostname: "A-{{.Task.Slot}}"
  deploy:
    replicas: 2
  B:
  environment:
    - SERVICEA=http://A-{{.Task.Slot}}/
  deploy:
    replicas: 2
```